# Ilogical 'double free or corruption (fasttop)' error

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm doing some Binary Search Tree homework and this "double free or corruption (fasttop)" error came out.

```
*** Error in `./bin/Main': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000c25c20 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f9546af77e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f9546b0037a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f9546b0453c]
./bin/Main[0x400f21]
./bin/Main[0x400e1b]
./bin/Main[0x400d8c]
./bin/Main[0x400cc0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f9546aa0830]
./bin/Main[0x400b69]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 6594                       /home/alu0101228587/c++_projects/bin/Main
00402000-00403000 r-xp 00002000 00:00 6594                       /home/alu0101228587/c++_projects/bin/Main
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 00:00 6594                       /home/alu0101228587/c++_projects/bin/Main
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 00:00 6594                       /home/alu0101228587/c++_projects/bin/Main
00c14000-00c46000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f9540000000-7f9540021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9540021000-7f9544000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9546770000-7f9546878000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 811272             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9546878000-7f954687a000 ---p 00108000 00:00 811272             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f954687a000-7f9546a77000 ---p 0000010a 00:00 811272             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9546a77000-7f9546a78000 r--p 00107000 00:00 811272             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9546a78000-7f9546a79000 rw-p 00108000 00:00 811272             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9546a80000-7f9546c40000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 808634             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9546c40000-7f9546c49000 ---p 001c0000 00:00 808634             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9546c49000-7f9546e40000 ---p 000001c9 00:00 808634             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9546e40000-7f9546e44000 r--p 001c0000 00:00 808634             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9546e44000-7f9546e46000 rw-p 001c4000 00:00 808634             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9546e46000-7f9546e4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9546e50000-7f9546e66000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 808707             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9546e66000-7f9547065000 ---p 00000016 00:00 808707             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9547065000-7f9547066000 rw-p 00015000 00:00 808707             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9547070000-7f95471e2000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 840863             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f95471e2000-7f95471ef000 ---p 00172000 00:00 840863             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f95471ef000-7f95473e2000 ---p 0000017f 00:00 840863             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f95473e2000-7f95473ec000 r--p 00172000 00:00 840863             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f95473ec000-7f95473ee000 rw-p 0017c000 00:00 840863             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f95473ee000-7f95473f2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9547400000-7f9547425000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 808510             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9547425000-7f9547426000 r-xp 00025000 00:00 808510             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9547625000-7f9547626000 r--p 00025000 00:00 808510             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9547626000-7f9547627000 rw-p 00026000 00:00 808510             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9547627000-7f9547628000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9547750000-7f9547751000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9547760000-7f9547761000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9547770000-7f9547772000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9547780000-7f9547781000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9547790000-7f9547791000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f95477a0000-7f95477a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fffe8039000-7fffe8839000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                  [stack]
7fffe8f7c000-7fffe8f7d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vdso]
```

This is the **Main program:**

```
#include "bsearch_tree_s.cpp"
#include "../include/dni.hpp"

int main(void)
{   
  bsearch_tree_s<int> tree;

  tree.insert(20);
  tree.insert(6);
  tree.insert(1);
  tree.insert(90);
  tree.insert(23);

  tree.write(cout);

  return 0;
}
```

It's very simple because I just wanted to test my class.

The thing is, by commenting lines in the Main program I noticed that the method that was creating the error was btree_c::insert(int).

**b_search_tree_c class (son) header file:**

```
#ifndef __BSEARCH_TREE_S__
#define __BSEARCH_TREE_S__

#include "../src/btree_c.cpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename Clave = int>
class bsearch_tree_s: public btree_c<Clave>
{   public:
        bsearch_tree_s(void);

        bsearch_tree_s(bnode_c<Clave>*);

        ~bsearch_tree_s(void);

        ostream& write(ostream&) const;
};

#endif
```

**bsearch_tree_c class (son) cpp file:**

```
#include "../include/bsearch_tree_s.hpp"

template <typename Clave>
bsearch_tree_s<Clave>::bsearch_tree_s(void):
btree_c<Clave>::btree_c() {}

template <typename Clave>
bsearch_tree_s<Clave>::~bsearch_tree_s(void)
{ btree_c<Clave>::~btree_c(); }

template <typename Clave>
ostream& bsearch_tree_s<Clave>::write(ostream& os) const
{   
  unsigned int root_level = 0;

  return btree_c<Clave>::print(os, btree_c<Clave>::root_, root_level);
}
```

**btree_c class (parent) header file:**

```
#ifndef __BTREE_C__
#define __BTREE_C__

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

#include "../src/bnode_c.cpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename Clave = int>
class btree_c
{   
    protected:
        int depth_;

        unsigned int size_;

        bnode_c<Clave>* root_;

    public:
        btree_c(void);

        btree_c(bnode_c<Clave>*);

        ~btree_c(void);

        void cut(bnode_c<Clave>*);

        bool is_empty(void) const;

        ostream& print(ostream&, bnode_c<Clave>*, unsigned int) const;

        void insert(const Clave);

        bnode_c<Clave>* get_root(void) const;

    private:
        void insert_branch(const Clave, bnode_c<Clave>*&);
};

#endif
```

**btree_c class (parent) cpp file:**

```
#include "../include/btree_c.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename Clave>
btree_c<Clave>::btree_c(void):
depth_(-1),
size_(0),
root_(NULL) {}


template <typename Clave>
btree_c<Clave>::btree_c(bnode_c<Clave>* root):
depth_(0),
size_(1),
root_(root) {}


template <typename Clave>
btree_c<Clave>::~btree_c(void) { cut(root_); }


template <typename Clave>
void btree_c<Clave>::cut(bnode_c<Clave>* node)
{   if (node == NULL) return;

    cut(node->left_);
    cut(node->right_);

    delete node;
    node = NULL;
}

template <typename Clave>
ostream& btree_c<Clave>::print(ostream& os, bnode_c<Clave>* node, unsigned int level) const
{   if (node == NULL) return os;

    else
    {   
        os << "Level " << level << ": [" << node->get_data() << "]  " << endl;

        level++;

        print(os, node->left_, level);
        print(os, node->right_, level);

        return os;
    }
}

template <typename Clave>
void btree_c<Clave>::insert(const Clave clave)
{   if (root_ == NULL)
      root_ = new bnode_c<Clave>(clave);
    else 
      insert_branch(clave, root_);

    size_++;
}

template <typename Clave>
void btree_c<Clave>::insert_branch(const Clave clave, bnode_c<Clave>*& node)
{   if (node == NULL)
        node = new bnode_c<Clave>(clave);

    else if (clave < node->get_data())
        insert_branch(clave, node->left_);

    else insert_branch(clave, node->right_);
}
```

**bnode_c header file:**

```
#ifndef __BNODE_C__
#define __BNODE_C__

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <typename TDato = int>
class bnode_c
{   private:
        TDato data_;

    public:
        bnode_c<TDato>* left_;

        bnode_c<TDato>* right_;

        bnode_c(void);

        bnode_c(const TDato&);

        ~bnode_c(void);

        TDato& get_data(void);
};

#endif
```

**bnode_c class cpp file:**

```
#include "../include/bnode_c.hpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename TDato>
bnode_c<TDato>::bnode_c(void):
    left_(NULL),
    right_(NULL),
    data_(NULL) {}

template <typename TDato>
bnode_c<TDato>::bnode_c(const TDato& dat):
    left_(NULL),
    right_(NULL),
    data_(dat) {}


template <typename TDato>
bnode_c<TDato>::~bnode_c(void)
{   left_ = NULL;

    right_ = NULL;
}

template <typename TDato>
TDato& bnode_c<TDato>::get_data(void) { return data_;}
```

I don't know how to solve this because I never had this error in my code, so I need your help.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I thought that the code I posted was enough. What do you think I should add?

Comment: I'd guess the error is in the bsearch_tree destructor: I don't see any explicit or implicit deletes in the insert code.

Comment: And Sam is asking for code that we can actually compile and run to reproduce the error, not just fragments to read, which can be useful when there's something non-obvious or tricky. I'm surprised you don't get a usable call stack with the error, though: are you compiling this with debug symbols (e.g. `-g` with gcc)?

Comment: @Rup do you think I should post the entire cpp from each class? I don't want the post to be too long or convoluted.

Also, I edited the post and added the destructors. I don't see anything unusual.

Comment: No, posting everything is too much yes: I think the idea is you edit it down to the minimal amount of code that will still reproduce the problem e.g. remove most of the methods from the classes that aren't being called, and often creating the simplest possible example like this will help you find the problem. (You'll find a lot of people get upset if you don't post a minimal complete example like this, even when there's enough information to answer the question already, which is think is silly and wrong, but there you go.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bsearch_tree_s destructor is calling its superclass destructor explicitly:

```
template <typename Clave>
bsearch_tree_s<Clave>::~bsearch_tree_s(void)
{ btree_c<Clave>::~btree_c(); }
```

This is wrong: it doesn't need to do that, it will be called automatically anyway, and the effect is that ~btree_c() will try and delete its `root_` node twice hence the error. It might be worth temporarily adding trace output to ~bsearch_tree_s and ~btree_c to see this.

You do clear the `node` pointer in `cut` after you've deleted it, but because this is passed by value not reference this won't change the root_ member. An alternative fix would be to set `root_ = NULL;` in ~btree_c() after you have `cut` it.

Comment: Yes, once I commented the call to `~btree_c()` in `~bsearch_tree_s()` it all worked fine. I also  removed the `node = NULL` line in `~btree_c()` because it was useless as @Surt sugested.

Comment: Also, does this also apply on constructors?

Comment: You can call the superclass constructor from the initialisation list, but you don't need to unless you want to pass it arguments - it will be called automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename Clave>
void btree_c<Clave>::cut(bnode_c<Clave>* node)
{   if (node == NULL) return;

    cut(node->left_);
    cut(node->right_);

    delete node;
    node = NULL; <---- this doesn't do anything
}
```

it needs an added & to do something.

```
void btree_c<Clave>::cut(bnode_c<Clave>*& node)
```